# How to run python script remotely on raspberry pi from another machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, command-line, raspberry-pi

My first piece of code is inside of my pc which detects characters at a part of the screen. Once it detects a certain sequence then it needs to send a signal to the raspberry pi which controls LEDs. I know that I can use SSH to run things remotely on a raspberry pi. But how do I automate it?

For example if I have the following code inside of my main pc

```
if numbs == [1,1,2]:
    #enter this code into the ssh to run leds.py on the raspberry
```

The pi is running standard Linux based raspbian.

If you have any other suggestions on better ways of doing this I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate anything on linux(raspbian in particular) in many ways.

First option is to use `cron` command. I'd say it is a simplest option, and pretty powerful: you can run your code once a minute, once a day, on each fridady 13th, etc.

Another option is writing systemd service for your task. Its pretty hard way, but even more powerful then the first one.

Another option special for python scripts is python package [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), which is kinda like prevoius solutions.

Comment: thats not really what i want, i can go multiple ways but the main idea is to send data from a windows machine to a raspberry pi

Comment: Again there are lots of ways. Simpest one is to connect them by ethernet or wifi and send data through http. There are http client and server implementation in python - `http.server` and `http.client`. Another option is to use usb cable, but i'm not sure about how to work with usb on Windows